# How can I save JSON data in an array to Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save a JSON data to Firestore.
The data is as follows:

```
[{"back":"democracy","delayed_till":{"seconds":1574944200,"nanoseconds":0},"examples":[{"answer":"en Espana existe democracia desde 1975","example":"There is democracy in Spain since 1975"},{"answer":"Debemos luchar por nuestra democracia","example":"We must fight for our democracy"}],"front":"la democracia"},{"back":"habit, custom","delayed_till":{"seconds":1575148500,"nanoseconds":0},"front":"la costumbre"},{"back":"krokodil","delayed_till":{"seconds":1577831400,"nanoseconds":0},"front":"roos"},{"back":"krokodil","front":"blabla"},{"back":"bjkla","front":"blabla"}]
```

saving it to Firestore in the following does not work because the JSON data is stored in an array

```
db.collection('cardsb').add(object)
```

Using the following only saves the first object within the JSON data.

```
db.collection('cardsb').add(object[0])
```

The part that will be saved is the following:

```
{"back":"democracy","delayed_till":{"seconds":1574944200,"nanoseconds":0},"examples":[{"answer":"en Espana existe democracia desde 1975","example":"There is democracy in Spain since 1975"},{"answer":"Debemos luchar por nuestra democracia","example":"We must fight for our democracy"}],"front":"la democracia"}
```

How can I get the whole data to be saved in one document?

**EDIT**

This is how the JSON data is created:

```
cons () {
      const nbrGroups = this.cards.length
      for (let i = 0; i < nbrGroups; i++) {
        var object = []
        const nbrItems = this.cards[i].group.length
        for (let item = 0; item < nbrItems; item++) {
          var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inFront, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inBack, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inAnswer, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inExample')
          const examples = []
          if (inputs.length !== 2) {
            for (let i = 2; i < inputs.length; i++) {
              examples.push({ answer: inputs[i + 1].value, example: inputs[i].value })
              i++
            }
            object.push({
              back: inputs[1].value,
              delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
              examples,
              front: inputs[0].value
            })
          } else {
            object.push({
              back: inputs[1].value,
              delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
              front: inputs[0].value
            })
          }
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(object))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(object) === JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].group))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].group))
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.cards[i].id))
        db.collection('cardsb').add(object[0])
      }
```

This is how it *should* be stored in FB:

[image]

This is what *actually* is stored

[image]

Comment: Please update your question to show how `object` is populated, or include code that does `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` and include the logged output in your question. It'd also help if you show (probably with a screenshot of the Firebase console) what *is* stored in Firestore, and (probably with a manually created document) what you *want* stored instead.

Comment: The native data type for a Firestore document is an object (map).  It doesn't store arrays, except as fields of document.

Comment: @Frank I updated my question. I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: NB: There is no JSON there. You pass JavaScript objects/arrays to Firestore, not JSON.

Comment: What if you do `.add({ group: object})`

Comment: @trincot `.add({ group: object})` does not work either. .add({ group: object[0]}) does but only saves the first part

Answer (score 1):

Just stringify the JSON before you send it, it will be stored as strings in firestore and when you need to retrieve it back you just need to parse it.

Example.

```
const jsonArray = JSON.stringify({
  foo: bar,
  sam: mas,
  hello: "world",
  createdAt: Date.now()
})

await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('COLLECTION_NAME')
  .doc("DOC_ID")
  .update({
    arrayField: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(jsonArray)
  })
  .then(async (resp) => { })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.code)
  });
```

This way you will save the json data as string inside array field in firestore

when you need to retrieve it back all you have to do is to use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
JSON.parse(fieldName)
```

your data will be store like this picture

[image: firestore image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're just writing the data to Firestore too early. You should only write once you've processes all groups, and at that point should write them all at one.

So something like:

```
  const nbrGroups = this.cards.length
  var object = []; // Move this before the for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < nbrGroups; i++) {
    const nbrItems = this.cards[i].group.length
    for (let item = 0; item < nbrItems; item++) {
      var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inFront, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inBack, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inAnswer, #' + this.cards[i].group_name.replace(/\s/g, '') + item + 'A #inExample')
      const examples = []
      if (inputs.length !== 2) {
        for (let i = 2; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          examples.push({ answer: inputs[i + 1].value, example: inputs[i].value })
          i++
        }
        object.push({
          back: inputs[1].value,
          delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
          examples,
          front: inputs[0].value
        })
      } else {
        object.push({
          back: inputs[1].value,
          delayed_till: this.cards[i].group[item].delayed_till,
          front: inputs[0].value
        })
      }
    }
  }
  db.collection('cardsb').add(object[0]); // move this after the for loop
```

Comment: It may seem that this is what should be done, but this is not what I am looking for. Lets assume that I want to store the data (for which I mistakenly wrote it was JSON data but like trincot mentioned is actually an object). Can it be saved to Firestore entirely?

Comment: I tried the following but that does not work either:
`{"group":[{"back":"democracy","delayed_till":{"seconds":1574944200,"nanoseconds":0},"examples":[{"answer":"en Espana existe democracia desde 1975","example":"There is democracy in Spain since 1975"},{"answer":"blabla","example":"more blabla"}],"front":"la democracia"},{"back":"habit, custom","delayed_till":{"seconds":1575148500,"nanoseconds":0},"front":"la costumbre"},{"back":"krokodil","delayed_till":{"seconds":1577831400,"nanoseconds":0},"front":"roos"},{"back":"krokodil","front":"blabla"},{"back":"bjkla","front":"blabla"}]}`

Comment: trying to save that to Firestore results in an error `Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined"`

Comment: I tried with this exact object and it worked for me.